# Powershell Set/Get-GPPermission missing from Group Policy on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, group-policy, windows-10

Recently updated from windows 7 enterprise to windows 10 enterprise and went to run a script that has a call to Get-GPPermision and it errored out as missing that command. Edit: Set-GPPermission is also missing.

checking for commands inside the group policy cmdlet shows that yes it is missing:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-command -Module grouppolicy

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                             
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                             
Cmdlet          Backup-GPO                                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Copy-GPO                                           1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Get-GPInheritance                                  1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Get-GPO                                            1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Get-GPOReport                                      1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Get-GPPrefRegistryValue                            1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Get-GPRegistryValue                                1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Get-GPStarterGPO                                   1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Import-GPO                                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          New-GPLink                                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          New-GPO                                            1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          New-GPStarterGPO                                   1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Remove-GPLink                                      1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Remove-GPO                                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Remove-GPPrefRegistryValue                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Remove-GPRegistryValue                             1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Rename-GPO                                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Restore-GPO                                        1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Set-GPInheritance                                  1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Set-GPLink                                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Set-GPPrefRegistryValue                            1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy                                        
Cmdlet          Set-GPRegistryValue                                1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
```

Here's the version table:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                             
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.693                                                                                     
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                           
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                           
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.693                                                                                    
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                   
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                               
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                               
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

The latest (posted last month) I can find shows the command stil there: https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/group-policy/index

Note: it appears that Microsoft has broken backwards compatibility since the calls were named Get-GPPermissions and Set-GPPermissions in group policy with powershell 4, now they droped the 's' and are both named singular Get-GPPermission and Set-GPPermission.

Anyone know how I can re-install the module?

**Edit:** module re-install was easy it was just a case  of uninstalling RSAT and then re-installing that. Sadly the command is still not showing up so my question should now be how to regain the missing commands.

Comment: What build of Windows 10 are you using?  It might be a Build 1607 thing.

Comment: It's version 1607 (OS build 14393.693). So what is a "Build 1607 thing"?

Comment: OK I read about 1607 issuesnow but they seem like last year's thing. Still happening huh? A bit disappointing with "enterprise software" I use powershell a lot for admin. Guess I'll have to go back to win 7 to use that group policy command. If there's a way you can demonstrate that it is a 1607 issue put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: What?  I meant that I didn't think that commandlet existed until 1607.  You say you have it on Windows 7?  You mention 'upgrade'/  Surely you meant clean install with Windows 10?  Are you sure you have the newest version of RSAT installed?

Comment: My fellow sysadmin created an SCCM upgrade package for win 7 --> win 10  and I used that on my workstation (after testing on a nother system) and it just worked.  I was using get-gppermissions since  2014 on windows 7 to check when some of us folks forget to give the group edit permissions on GPOs. I'll need to check about the RSAT version and get back here. OK RSAT is what I downloaded 2/28/2017 and says build is RSAT-WS2015-x64

Comment: RSAT 2015? Try this.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520 It is WindowsTH-RSAT_WS2016-x64.msu

Comment: typo sorry, that already was the oct 2016 version which is stil the latest download

Comment: Wow.... On my Windows machines, the "s" was needed. It's a Windows Server 2008 R2 domain controller..... yes, I know Server 2008 is to soon be unsupported.... ha!

Answer (score 0):

After spending too many hours trying to debug this I gave up and re-imaged the system from scratch which fixed the issue. It's not an answer but it makes the question moot.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a Win10 client (with RSAT onboard?) to write down your script.
I'd suggest to import the *grouppolicy* module from a DC PSSession:

```
$DC = 'yourDomainController'
$Credentials = Get-Credentials 
$DCSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $DC -Credential $Credentials
Import-Module grouppolicy -PSSession $DCSession

##############

Get-Command -Module grouppolicy

CommandType     Name                                               Version    
Source                                                                                                                                                                 
-----------     ----                                               -------    -- 
Function        Backup-GPO                                         1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Copy-GPO                                           1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Get-GPInheritance                                  1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Get-GPO                                            1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Get-GPOReport                                      1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Get-GPPermissions                                  1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Get-GPPrefRegistryValue                            1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Get-GPRegistryValue                                1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy                         1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Get-GPStarterGPO                                   1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Import-GPO                                         1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        New-GPLink                                         1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        New-GPO                                            1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        New-GPStarterGPO                                   1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Remove-GPLink                                      1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Remove-GPO                                         1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Remove-GPPrefRegistryValue                         1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Remove-GPRegistryValue                             1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Rename-GPO                                         1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Restore-GPO                                        1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Set-GPInheritance                                  1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Set-GPLink                                         1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Set-GPPermissions                                  1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Set-GPPrefRegistryValue                            1.0        grouppolicy                                                                                                                                                            
Function        Set-GPRegistryValue                                1.0        grouppolicy
```

You can automate the credentials definition. Visit: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/add-credentials-to-powershell-functions?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/518098)